# Is it possible to create a workspace with an Xcode Project Template?

Tags: ios, xcode, project-template

Is it possible to create a workspace using a `TemplateInfo.plist` option? I haven't found any documentation<sup>1</sup>, so I suspect that it's not possible.

However, if it is possible, how are multiple projects added to that workspace please?

---

<sup>1. Project templates aren't *officially* documented anywhere. The "documentation" I refer to is community based.</sup>